# How to list all pods running on windows nodes

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to list all pods which are running on windows nodes with `--field-selector` help. All of them have nodeSelector:

```
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: windows
```

I am doing:

`kubectl get pods -A -o wide --field-selector 'spec.nodeSelector.kubernetes.io/os=windows'`

But I am getting the error:

`Error from server (BadRequest): Unable to find "/v1, Resource=pods" that match label selector "", field selector "spec.nodeSelector.kubernetes.io/os=windows": field label not supported: spec.nodeSelector.kubernetes.io/os`

I guess I need to escape `kubernetes.io/os` somehow but I don't know how. I have already tried:

```
kubectl get pods -A -o wide --field-selector spec.nodeSelector.'kubernetes.io/os'=windows
kubectl get pods -A -o wide --field-selector spec.nodeSelector.kubernetes\.io/os=windows
kubectl get pods -A -o wide --field-selector "spec.nodeSelector."kubernetes.io/os"=windows"
```

and similar varations but no luck :(